# Flask returns 404 instead of 405 for defined endpoint

Tags: python, flask

Puzzling: all endpoints in a Flask app work correctly, except for one which returns 404 instead of the expected 405.

Minimal example:

```py
import flask

app = flask.Flask("testapp")

@app.route("/test/", methods=["POST"])
def test_post():
    return 'post'

@app.route("/test/", methods=["GET"])
def test_get():
    return 'get'
```

```bash
$ flask --app testapp run
```

Where:

- `curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:5000/test` works = returns 200 (OK), but
- `curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:5000/test` returns 404 (doesn't exist) instead of the expected 405 (method not allowed).

Any ideas why an endpoint that exists and works (GET and POST work fine) should ever return 404 when called with unrouted PUT?

This is using Flask 2.2.2 (latest) on Python 3.10. This used to work in older Flask 1.x, but my integration tests blew up after the upgrade to 2.2.2 and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the trailing slash? Does the usage above (consistently with a slash, in the request and in routes) match your actual application?

Comment: 404 for the `PUT` method is not reproducible on my PC, using 2.2.2 Flask too.

Comment: @Thomas Flask will automatically redirect `/test` (without the slash) to the canonical `/test/`. But an interesting idea, I'll test the route without the slash.

Comment: Yes that's it. `curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test'` reproduces the problem = gives 404 instead of 405. This used to work in Flask 1.x (both slash or no slash in request gave 405), I must have missed it in Flask's 2.0 changelog. Thanks @Thomas!

Comment: I suggest you post an answer to your own question; even though I pointed you in the right direction, you're better aware of the details.